# Multiple lands in MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What's the best way to play additional lands in a turn? I am assembling a black/white deck but want to play with cards that have higher casting cost. I do not, however, want my deck to lose speed as a result.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "mana ramp."  Green has lots of ways to play additional lands.  Black and White have few/none.  The typical approach is to find artifacts to add mana.

Comment: Can you indicate which format you're interested in?  That will affect the answers as well.

Comment: Your question is a bit more specific so that isn't a perfect duplicate, but I think it pretty well covers what kinds of things you could look for.

Comment: Look for cards that reduce the cost of your spells. White and Blue tend to do that. Black has some spells that generate mana in a pinch.